# How can i fix the "Type.IsGenericParameter is true." error?

Tags: c#, dll, reflection, loading

I get the "Method may only be called on a Type for which Type.IsGenericParameter is true." from this code below. I get that error on the last line of this code. , i dont know how to fix that.

```
byte[] domainMainDllFileBuffer = null;
string domainMainFilePath = "myDllPath...";
FileStream domainMainFs = new FileStream(domainMainFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
BinaryReader domainMainBr = new BinaryReader(domainMainFs);
long domainMainNumBytes = new FileInfo(domainMainFilePath).Length;
domainMainDllFileBuffer = domainMainBr.ReadBytes((int)domainMainNumBytes);

System.Reflection.Assembly domainMainAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(domainMainDllFileBuffer);
IEnumerable<Type> domainMainTypes = domainMainAssembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.BaseType != null);
```

Comment: I'm assuming you get the error at the last line of the code you copied? Please include this information in your question.

Comment: yes i get it there, i added this information to the question, thank you for warning me

Comment: The only Type that would have `t.BaseType == null` is `object` itself, so this `Where` statement doesn't do anything here.

Comment: @golergka - or an interface - see the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.type.basetype.aspx). Of course, an `IsInterface` check would be more logical...

Comment: You're right, I forgot about them.

Comment: i used that code for interface, i changed as you say @Damien_The_Unbeliever but its still giving me the same error

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to read the DLL in binary format?

You can just use:

```
Assembly.LoadFrom("myDllPath...");
```

Otherwise I can't really see why you are getting that error. The only method you are calling on the assembly is GetTypes() and you are not really calling any method on the types themselves.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get that exception you must be calling `.GenericParameterAttributes` or `.GenericParameterPosition` (or some similar method) somewhere that you've not posted. If that's the case, you can verify that the type is a generic parameter first:

```
if(type.IsGenericParameter)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: no, i am not calling one of these methods, i have two dll's. one of them gives this error, one of them not, i dont understand why

Comment: What do you _do_ with `domainMainTypes`?

Comment: i will get the names of the domains classes from that dll, the name isnt correct, i know abpout that